# Escape sequence for OR ( | ) in lex

Tags: c++, escaping, lex

I am trying to define a regex in lex, `[>|<|\|]` which matches `<` or `>` or `|`
However, the `gcc compiler` generates a warning of

> **unknown escape sequence: '\|' [enabled by default]**

How do I match for **|**?

Comment: don't use a nonexistent escape sequence (which `\|` is).

Comment: Have you tried to surround the "|" with quotation?

Comment: Which |, the last one??

Comment: The one that need to be escaped...

Comment: If you are getting a compiler error from gcc, you've done something other than define a flex pattern. You'll need to paste more of your scanner definition, though. (And, yes, the flex pattern you're looking for is `[<>|]`, as in @angew's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

In a regex, `[]` delimits character classes. `|` has no special meaning inside a character class. So the regex is just:

```
[<>|]
```